# How to view short descriptions of all bash builtin commands?

Tags: bash

Well, the command `help` returns a two column list which includes the syntax of all builtin commands.

The command `help -d` returns exactly the same as above.

The command `help -d printf` returns a short description of the command `printf`:

```
printf - Formats and prints ARGUMENTS under control of the FORMAT.
```

The command `help -d p` returns short descriptions of all the commands starting with `p`:

```
popd - Remove directories from stack.
printf - Formats and prints ARGUMENTS under control of the FORMAT.
pushd - Add directories to stack.
pwd - Print the name of the current working directory.
```

So, is there some way of producing a list of short descriptions for **all** commands?

Comment: I suggest `help -d \*` or `help -d "*"`?

Comment: I tried `help -d *` and it didn't work. I wonder why I didn't think of backslash or quotes. Probably too tired. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the command you're looking for:

```
help -d ''
```

This works because `help` expects a pattern as the final argument, and an empty pattern will match all topics. You can pass an empty argument to a command by using `''` or `""`.

I suspect the `help` source code contains a statement like the following pseudocode:

```
if (pattern) {
    results = search(pattern);
    print(results);
}
else {
    print(OVERVIEW_TABLE)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works as well as Cyrus's suggestions on previous comment. Can you provide some explanation or link to an explanation to understand why this works?